# How to unit test Mongo ClusterBuilder Subscriptions?

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing

Mongo's driver for C# allows you to subscribe to cluster events like

```
Subscribe<CommandSucceededEvent>(ev => Log(ev) );
Subscribe<CommandFailedEvent>(ev => Log(ev) );
Subscribe<WhateverEvent>(ev => Log(ev) );
```

How can I unit test that all the required subscriptions occurred? that no one deleted anything incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no publicly accessible way to check what events subscribers are configured. You can use reflection and check a private collection with subscribers inside cluster builder, but it's not a reliable solution.

If you need to have extra confidence that you've subscribed on all events you need (not sure what is the real value here though..), use a different overload for [Subscribe](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Core_Configuration_ClusterBuilder_Subscribe.htm) where you can put an own IEventSubscriber implementation and check it accordingly.